# Could a 24 pin motherboard connector be used for a 24v sprinkler system quick connect? If not do similar multi terminal connectors exist?

Tags: voltage, wiring, wire-terminals

I'm doing a project where I need to be able to connect/disconnect multiple 24v wires. Instead of connecting each one individually, I'd like to just hook them all up to a molex connector and be able to quickly connect/disconnect them. I was thinking I could cannibalize a motherboard power connector, because it meets the requirements I need (robust, can't be connected backwards, lots of connections), but am not sure if it would accept 24v. Would it work with 24v, and if not, is there a type of connector I could use?

Comment: You need to know both the voltage AND the current. There are lots of standard Molex type crimp connectors you can use for this.

Comment: Sprinkler system sounds like water and outdoors.  Those connectors are not really weather/water proof.  Also I'm not sure that the assembly is rated for that voltage/current.

Comment: Have a look at that: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=sealed_connectors

Comment: @BadgerBadger The control unit (and proposed connector) would be safely indoors

Comment: WHere do u live and does Digikey ship there?

Comment: The voltage/current issue remains.  I know Phoenix connectors are rated for 48v with a pretty high current.  Maybe that would be a better option (cheaper than specialized molex connectors) for you.

Comment: Digikey or Mouser are equivalent. If one does not ship, maybe the other does.

Comment: @trevor Kansas, so most likely yes.

Comment: Then go look here https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20 they have literally thousands of varieties to chose from... but they do need a tool to help you find what you want...

Comment: Any connector big enough to see with the naked eye will be good for carrying 'touch-safe' voltages, say <= 40v, though not necessarily for breaking the connection under power. The mobo molex will be good for a few amps per pin.